# I am using react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer. Code page for hindi

Tags: react-native, encoding, bluetooth, hindi, escpos

```
BluetoothEscposPrinter.printText("नमस्कार\r\n", {
                                    encoding: '',
                                    codepage: 22,
                                });
```

my code and it's not working.

Comment: There are these articles, and you can see comments like your question. However, it does not seem to be resolved. [Encoding UTF-8 #8](https://github.com/januslo/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer/issues/8), [Does it not support Thai language? #33](https://github.com/januslo/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer/issues/33) Before that, does your printer support Hindi printing? Before that, does your printer support Hindi printing? Even if it does, if the method is vendor-specific, it's unlikely that it's supported by a published library. I think it's better to check it first.

Comment: Yes, it supports.

Comment: In that case, please compare the specifications of the Hindi character printing control code supported by the printer with the published source code of the library. If you do that, you can see if the library supports the printer specifications.

Comment: what packages r u using and does it work for english